# How to disable a preloader?

Tags: webpack

I have set up [jshinting with webpack](https://github.com/webpack/jshint-loader), but I want to load a specific file as javascript without linting it. My jshint is set up as a *preLoader*

```
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
        loader: "jshint-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have tried to disable this preloader like so:

`require('!script!../../lib/bootstrap');`

Because [the documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) states that:

> adding ! to a request will disable configured preLoaders
>   require("!raw!./script.coffee")

However, when I do this, the file is still linted:

> WARNING in ./~/script-loader/~/raw-loader!./~/jshint-loader!./lib/bootstrap.js
>   jshint results in errors...

If I use this require:

`require('!!script!../../lib/bootstrap');`

The linting does not occur.

What is happening here and why can't I disable this preloader using the recommended method of disabling preloaders?